# Formatting ordoned list float left

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with displaying a big ordoned list. Here I wrote just for 1000, but imagine how will look for 100000 elements.

Anyway maybe that won't be a problem to big, but after 9999, the 1 from 10000 get hidden.

```
    1. Element 1
    2. Element 1
   10. Element 10
  100. Element 100
 1000. Element 1000
```

To avoid that I would like to display it like:

```
  1. Element 1
  2. Element 1
  10. Element 10
  100. Element 100
  1000. Element 1000
```

I tried to put `float:right` on `li` and `ol li` but didn't help.
Is there any css trick that can help with this?

```
.list ol li {
        margin-left:55px;

}

//margin-left:55px to avoid hidding first digit. Ugly method, I know.

.list ol li {
        float:right;
                position:relative;   
}
```

`.list` is the class containing this ordoned list.

Comment: Please post the markup and css which you have tried.

Comment: Although you might not be interested in UI/UX, but the way you want the list to appear is not a good User Experience, It will fail badly in terms of readability.

Comment: @Gaurav, in this case this seems to bee a good UI/UX solution too. Just think that I have at 100, 1000, 10000, 100000 elements until the text will be moved because of +1 number of ordered list.  But, anyway, you are right, I was more interested of the technical solution instead of the UI/UX.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul{border:1px solid red;padding:0;margin:0;list-style:decimal inside;position:relative;}

   <ul>
      <li>Element 1</li>
     <li>Element 2</li>
     <li>Element 3</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! That was the solution. Can you exaplain me what `list-style:decimal inside none;` does? I mean that `inside none`.

Comment: sorry , my friend list-style:decimal inside;

Answer (score 0):

Use this to left align the ordered list -

HTML:

```
<ol>
        <li>Element 1</li>
        <li>Element 2</li>
        <li>Element 3</li>
        <li>Element 4</li>
        <li>Element 5</li>
        <li>Element 6</li>
        <li>Element 7</li>
        <li>Element 8</li>
        <li>Element 9</li>
        <li>Element 10</li>
        <li>Element 11</li>
    </ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol{ list-style-position: inside;}
```

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/dfwL8/)**</kbd>

You can use `list-style` as

```
ol {
    list-style: <list-style-type> || <list-style-position> || <list-style-image>;
}
```

You need `list-style-position : inside` as below

```
ol {
    list-style:decimal inside none;
}
```

[**Read here for more details**](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/list-style/)